# Issue with boost::memory-mapping ~500MB, external USB file

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files

I am using the below code to open files which are approximately 400 to 800MB in size:

```
#include <boost\interprocess\file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    file_mapping fm("C:\\test\\1.txt",read_only);
    mapped_region region(fm,read_only);
    const char* const data = static_cast<const char*>(region.get_address());
    const size_t max_size = region.get_size();

    cout << max_size;

    int b;
    cin >> b;
}
```

If I point the above code to a small file I get no exception. However, when looking at the several-hundred-MB-files (on an external USB) I get an exception:

> Unhandled exception at at 0x7521C41F in ReadingFiles.exe: Microsoft
>   C++ exception: boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception at memory
>   location 0x0040FBD4.

I have 2.4GB of RAM free- so it shouldnt be that I have run out of memory?

Comment: 32bit program? 32bit windows?

Comment: I think that was the solution (32bit program). Put it as answer and i'll accept. Thanks

Comment: Note that a 32 bit windows program can only use 2Gb of memory address space. (And in that address space there's pieces of .dlls, code, heap,  and so on already mapped, further decreasing the available memory a 32 bit process can allocate space from

Comment: A piece of advice irrelevant to your question: use forward slashes as in `#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>`; this way it works both in Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is compiled as 32bit program your are most likely out of memory. Sort of. 2.4GB free does not necessarily mean 2.4GB free continuous memory. You might not be able to get a sufficiently large chunk of it to map your file.